# flutter: is there a way to write data to json and read them on another screen?

Tags: flutter

i'm new to flutter and i want to create a small app that can be used by 3 users, first user will write to do list and the two others can read them on different devices on ***real time*** ... is there a way to write a list into JSON file and the read it from other devices in real time?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) does exactly what you are looking for. It synchronizes a JSON file between all connected clients in realtime. What's more is that it has an [an official Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database) and [clear instructions on how to start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/start#initialize_the_firebase_realtime_database_package).

Before using it make sure you are [aware of the pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) but for only 3 users you should stay within the free limits.